# Rejected input for logistic regression curve

Tags: machine-learning, logistic-regression

I just started learning machine learning and am facing a problem with regards to creating my logistic regression model. My input, X is a binary string (ie it's a string with '1' and '0's), 2048 characters long. `len(X)` is 165. I need it as a string of 1 and 0 because it's an important input feature.

I got an error message *"Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64')"* and did not know how to resolve the error.

I have already eliminated the NaN values before assigning the values to X. The sum of NaN values are 0.

If anyone has any suggestions on what I can try to solve the error, do let me know. Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

can you post a screenshot of the data, cant actually understand what you mean by change the input ti binary, seeing the data will help, and please try and format your question well